# UIScrollView resizes when a UIViewController is pushed in UINavigationController. Why?

Tags: iphone

When I push a UIViewController within a UINavigationController, the UIScrollView in the view changes dimensions. Now even I am trying to resize the UIScrollView. It wont simply resize. It maintains the framework dimensions. Any idea why this would be happening.

Example:

My NIB has a view which has a scrollview with dimensions (320, 430)

now when I push the UIViewController associated with the view the scrollview still shows dimensions has 320, 430, but is drawn much smaller then 320,430 [alt text http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6554/screenve.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6554/screenve.png)

Any suggestions in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of the autosizing mask property of the view i created programmatically was set. Resetting the flag solved the problem.